# How to get most recent date in a Map<Long, Date>?

Tags: java, date, collections, hashmap, treemap

Hi i need to get the id of the most recent date contained in a `Map`.

The id is a unique `Long` number that identifies the date.

```
Map<Long, Date> mapRetrieveMostRecent= new HashMap<Long, Date>();
```

I filled the map in this way:

```
mapRetrieveMostRecent.put(id, xDate);
```

I know that `TreeMap` can insert automatically objects sorting by date but in my case the dates aren't unique.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: yes I am @FranciscoTena

Comment: as the output of you need list of keys that have the same max date ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the key of maximum date you can use the following one-liner

```
Long keyMax = Collections.max(mapRetrieveMostRecent.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the values in the map in O(n), if that's feasible for you:

```
Map<Long, Date> mapRetrieveMostRecent= new HashMap<Long, Date>();
Date mostRecent = null;
for( Date d : mapRetrieveMostRecent.values())
{
    if( mostRecent == null || d.after( mostRecent))
        mostRecent = d;
}
```

Comment: Nice! In this way in the end i have the mostRecent Date but how can i access his Id Key in the map? (unfortunatly my Dates are not unique )

Comment: You can iterate over the key set for that, like this:  Map<Long, Date> mapRetrieveMostRecent= new HashMap<Long, Date>();
 Date mostRecent = null, current;
 long mostRecentId = -1;
 for( long id : mapRetrieveMostRecent.keySet())
 {
  current = mapRetrieveMostRecent.get( id);
     if( mostRecent == null || current.after( mostRecent))
     {
      mostRecent = current;
      mostRecentId = id;
     }
 }

Comment: That's perfect ! Can you only explain the meaning of
 " Date mostRecent = null, current; "
in the end of the statement MostRecent is equal to current ? How Is it possible for a variable to have 2 different values? 
Thank you!  @uoyilmaz

Comment: It doesn't have 2 different values, it is a shorthand for  Date mostRecent = null;
 Date current;
on 2 different statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8 I would take advantage of Comparable extension like this:

```
 public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V>  sortByValue( Map<K, V> map ){
     List<Map.Entry<K, V>> l = new LinkedList<>( map.entrySet() );
     Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
     {
         @Override
         public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> one, Map.Entry<K, V> another )
         {
             return (one.getValue()).compareTo( another.getValue() );
         }
     } );

     Map<K, V> r = new LinkedHashMap<>();
     for (Map.Entry<K, V> item : l)
     {
         r.put( item.getKey(), item.getValue() );
     }
     return r;
 }
```

I was trying [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) classes when I got this solution:

```
 Map<Long, Date> mapRetrieveMostRecent= new HashMap<>();
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 mapRetrieveMostRecent.put(1l, cal.getTime());
 cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
 mapRetrieveMostRecent.put(2l, cal.getTime());
 cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);
 mapRetrieveMostRecent.put(3l, cal.getTime());

 Map<Long, Date> mapRetrieveMostRecentOrdered = sortMap(mapRetrieveMostRecent);
 System.out.println("Sorted Map Ascending: " + Arrays.toString(mapRetrieveMostRecentOrdered.entrySet().toArray()));

 public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K,V> sortMap( Map<K,V> map){
        return map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));
 }
```

And the corresponding Test:

```
@Test
public void testSortByValue()
{
    int testSize = 50;
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Map<Long, Date> testMap = new HashMap<>(testSize);
    for(long i = 0 ; i < testSize ; ++i) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, random.nextInt());
        testMap.put(i, cal.getTime());
    }

    testMap = TenaTest.sortByValue( testMap );//Using compare
  //testMap = TenaTest.sortMap( testMap );//Using streams
    Assert.assertEquals( testSize, testMap.size() );

    Date previous = null;
    for(Map.Entry<Long, Date> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
        Assert.assertNotNull( entry.getValue() );
        if (previous != null) {
            Assert.assertTrue( entry.getValue().after(previous) );
        }
        previous = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a `TreeMap` would sort by `id`, since it sorts the keys, not the values.

Since your `Date` objects are values, you may want to iterate your map until you find the most recent `Date`.

Here's a long-ish example iterating the entry set and retrieving the ID for the latest `Date`.

Note that id the `Date`s aren't unique, you may be getting the id for *one* of the most recent `Date`s, if you have multiple `Date`s that are equal and most recent compared to others.

```
// your map
Map<Long, Date> map = new HashMap<Long, Date>();
// putting values
map.put(0l, new Date());
// putting values
map.put(0l, new Date(0l));
map.put(1l, new Date(1l));
map.put(2l, new Date(2l)); // this will be the most recent
Date latest = null;
Long latestID = null;
// iterating entry set
for (Map.Entry<Long, Date> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Date value = entry.getValue();
    Long key = entry.getKey();
    // initial comparison
    if (latest == null) {
        latest = value;
        latestID = key;
        continue;
    }
    // further comparisons
    if (value.after(latest)) {
        latest = value;
        latestID = key;
    }
}
System.out.println(latestID); // will print 2
```

Comment: Consider using any other constructors like new Date(long) instead of adding sleeps in your code

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I agree with the principle but this is just for testing. OP would actually have different `Date`s to start with.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto nevermind, it's prettier the way you're saying - edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can stream the entries and get the max using a comparator:

```
Map<Long, Date> mapRetrieveMostRecent = new HashMap<Long, Date>();
mapRetrieveMostRecent.entrySet().stream()
                     .max(Entry::comparingByValue)
                     .map(Entry::getKey)
                     .orElse([default value here]);
```

Comment: You're right - although the OP doesn't really say what he wants in case of multiple max dates.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that `TreeMap` can insert automatically objects sorting by date
>   but in my case the dates aren't unique. Any suggestions?

One option could be to use a [`TreeMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) from **Google Guava**, it sorts its keys like a `TreeMap` and it accepts duplicate values, to make it works in your case you will have to invert the key and the value as next:

```
// Create my map
TreeMultimap<Date, Long> mapRetrieveMostRecent =  TreeMultimap.create();
...
// Put an entry into my map
mapRetrieveMostRecent.put(xDate, id);
...
// Get all the ids corresponding to the most recent date
Collection<Long> ids = mapRetrieveMostRecent.asMap().lastEntry().getValue();
```

With this approach you will get **all the ids** corresponding to **the most recent** `Date` as you can have several ids matching the same `Date`.

---

Here is how it could be done in **Java 8** using the [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
Collection<Long> ids = mapRetrieveMostRecent.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new, toList()))
    .lastEntry()
    .getValue()
    .stream()
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(toList());
```